# unable to resolve dns after enable ipf

Tags: firewall, solaris

I running on Solaris 10 platform.

Before I enable IPF, I able to ping and traceroute to yahoo.com

After I enabled the IPf, I could not ping nor traceroute to yahoo.com
However when I ping to IP 69.147.114.224 (one of yahoo resolved IP) directly, it gives me response.

It seem to be that IPF block the DNS resolvability.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a firewall rule to allow UDP and TCP traffic on port 53.

Comment: UDP is a minimum default, since TCP is used to perform huge things like zone transfers between servers. DNS clients usually don't need that.

Comment: Do _not_ block DNS over TCP, you'll break large UDP responses.  See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dnsext-dns-tcp-requirements-01

Answer (score 1):

Add the pass out rule:
pass out quick from any to any keep state